# How to fix touch screen event with orientation conrols on android device?

Tags: three.js, webvr

I use threejs to make webvr and use deviceOrientationControls to controls on a mobile device it works fine on ios but android can't touch screen to tap a button, how I can fix it?

Note: ios can tap left and right button to switch content but Android can't

demo: https://demoviss.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fixed, I use touch event instead mouse event it's can work with ios android and desktop mouse.